# Canonical representation of a class object containing a list element in XML

Tags: xml

I see that most implementations of JAX-RS represent a class object containing a list of elements as follows (assume a class House containing a list of People)

```
<houses>
  <house>
    <person>
      <name>Adam</name>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>Blake</name>
    </person>
  </house>
  <house>
  </house>
</houses>
```

The result above is obtained for instance from Jersey 2 JAX-RS implementation,
notice Jersey creates a wrapper class "houses" around each house, however strangely it doesn't create a wrapper class around each person!
I don't feel this is a correct mapping of a list, in other words I'd feel more confortable with something like this:

```
<houses>
  <house>
    <persons>
    <person>
      <name>Adam</name>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>Blake</name>
    </person>
    </persons>
  </house>
  <house>
  </house>
</houses>
```

Is there any document explaining how an object should be correctly mapped apart from any opninion?

Answer (score 1):

XML documents can only have a single root node, so the `<houses>` is necessary if you would want to serialize more than one `<house>`.

A `<persons>` element is not necessary as a node may contain any number of children with the same tag name – they can be disambiguated by position. It adds complication without adding value or structure. But such a grouping may be adequate e.g. when we have different kinds of inhabitants in our house:

```
<house>
  <inhabitants>
    <human>
      <name>Larry</name>
    </human>
    <human>
      <name>Guido</name>
    </human>
    <dog>
      <name>Rasmus</name>
    </dog>
  </inhabitants>
</house>
```

Here, `<inhabitants>` encodes a *relation*, whereas `<human>` and `<dog>` encode a *type*.

Comment: Good point, however the next step I'd think of would be to user wrapper classes for consistency in every case, otherwise one would have to know each time whether a list might or might not contain elements of different types.